# managing permission and profiles

Tags: permission-sets

We run into issue with managing permission set and profile when developping with many developers. Is there any tool so that I can manage profile and permission set? I found it very annoying because I have to add classess and pages permission set and I need to merge profiles. I was wondering there is a better tool to manage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 tools that might be help,

Perm-Comparator
https://perm-comparator.herokuapp.com/

The Permissioner
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000008XYMlEAO

Here is the introduce video of these tools from Dreamforce
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZMH7yqJGo4